# Probability of Sum of numbers on two dice not divisible by 3 nor by 4

Tags: probability

Two dice are thrown together and we are asked to find the probability of the sum not being divisible by $3$ nor by $4$.
I took it as $ 1-P[3~or~4] $ . Where n(divisible by 3) is 4, n(divisible by 4) is 3 and n(divisible by both 3 and 4) is 1.
I got the answer as $\frac{5}{6}$ but the answer in the book is $\frac{4}{9}$.

Comment: Are you assuming that each possible sum is equally probable?

Comment: Yes, each sum has 1/36 probability.

Comment: So when you say n(divisible by 3) is 4 - which 4 sums are you counting, and what is the total probability of all the sums you are checking? Hint: if the total probabilty of your sample space isn't 1, you have a problem.

Comment: n(divisible by 3) is 4, which are (3,6,9,12)

Comment: Following your reasoning: All the sums are: {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}, which is 11 possibilities. If each sum has a probability of 1/36, then when I throw two dice I have an 11/36 chance of getting a sum in the range 2-12.
What happens in the other 25/36 of throws?

Comment: No. You have 36/36 chance of getting a sum in the range of 2 to 11.

Comment: As one particular sum can be obtained from various combinations of numbers.

Comment: Oh yes now I understood!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine how we could modify your approach to obtain the correct answer.

It is true that there are four multiples of $3$ whose sum can be obtained when rolling two distinguishable six-sided dice (say a red die and a white die).  They are $3$, $6$, $9$, $12$.  They can be obtained as follows:

\begin{array}{l l c}
\text{sum} & \text{possible outcomes} & \text{number of outcomes} \\ \hline 
3 & (\color{red}{1}, 2), (\color{red}{2}, 1) & 2\\
6 & (\color{red}{1}, 5), (\color{red}{2}, 4), (\color{red}{3}, 3), (\color{red}{4}, 2), (\color{red}{5}, 1) & 5\\
9 & (\color{red}{3}, 6), (\color{red}{4}, 5), (\color{red}{5}, 4), (\color{red}{6}, 3) & 4\\
12 & (\color{red}{6}, 6) & 1
\end{array} 
Hence, there are $2 + 5 + 4 + 1 = 12$ possible outcomes in which the sum is divisible by $3$.

It is also true that there are three multiples of $4$ whose sum can be obtained when rolling two distinguishable six-sided dice.  They are $4$, $8$, and $12$.  They can be obtained as follows:

\begin{array}{l l c}
\text{sum} & \text{possible outcomes} & \text{number of outcomes} \\ \hline 
4 & (\color{red}{1}, 3), (\color{red}{2}, 2), (\color{red}{3}, 1) & 3\\
8 & (\color{red}{2}, 6), (\color{red}{3}, 5), (\color{red}{4}, 4), (\color{red}{5}, 3), (\color{red}{6}, 2) & 5\\
12 & (\color{red}{6}, 6) & 1
\end{array} 
Hence, there are $3 + 5 + 1 = 9$ possible outcomes in which the sum is divisible by $4$.

However, since $12$ is divisible by both $3$ and $4$, we have counted the outcome $12$ twice.  Hence, there are $12 + 9 - 1 = 20$ outcomes in which the sum is divisible by $3$ or $4$.  Since there are $6 \cdot 6 = 36$ outcomes when two distinguishable six-sided dice are rolled, the number of outcomes in which the sum is not divisible by $3$ or $4$ is $36 - 20 = 16$.  Hence, the probability that the sum is divisible by neither $3$ nor $4$ is 
$$\frac{16}{36} = \frac{4}{9}$$ 
Where you went wrong was in not considering how often each sum occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Number of possible outcomes $=6\times6=36$

favourable outcomes = $\{(1,1),(1,4),(1,6),(2,3),(2,5),(3,2),(3,4),(4,1),(4,3),(4,6),(5,2),(5,5),(5,6),(6,1),(6,4),(6,5)\}$

Number of favourable outcomes $=16$

Probability $=\dfrac{16}{36}=\dfrac{4}{9}$

Comment: But (1,5) is divisible by 3

Comment: pl see the edit

Comment: Got it.. can you explain the mistake in my approach?